# Kotlin Spring Boot CORS "No mapping for OPTIONS /users"

Tags: spring-boot, rest, kotlin, cors

I have tried every solution I could find on stack overflow for my problem but nothing worked.

I have a CORS configuration in my kotlin app.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
class WebConfig : WebMvcConfigurer {
    override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
            .allowedOrigins("*")
            .allowedHeaders("*");
    }
}
```

And I have this controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("users")
class UserController(
    val userService: UserService
) {
    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping("/", produces = ["application/json"])
    fun createUser(@RequestBody user: User): User {
        return userService.createUser(user)
    }
}
```

When I call that endpoint from my Angular application I get the following error:

```
WARN 19441 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for OPTIONS /users
```

I can't seem to have the Global CORS working. How have you done this in Kotlin?

Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you remove `@CrossOrigin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you are calling is incorrect.

In your `@PostMapping` you registered `/users/` and not `/users`.

To fix this change your post mapping to `@PostMapping(produces = ["application/json"])` and it should be working.